# Suffix a term to every class generated

Tags: entity-framework

I am generating poco entititied using poco entity generator, that is fine.

But I want to sufix a term say "Entity" to every class generated.

Is ther any option for this ,such that every entity generated do have a sufix to it?

User will be  UserEntity

Role will be  RoleEntity

Comment: Why? Is there a superclass called Entity? Would you create an EntityEntity? An EntityEntityEntity? Where will the madness end?

Answer (score 0):

If you use POCO generator template you can simply open the template and modify it to use your new naming convention. You must modify type generation (and perhaps also file name generation) and navigation property generation.